# Cucumber Runner class & running tags from any Main Java Program

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I want to run the tags by calling the Cucumber class which is as below. How this can be achieved?

```
public class SuiteRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

        private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

        @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
        public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
            testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
        }

        @Test(dataProvider = "features")
        public void feature(PickleEventWrapper eventwrapper, CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
            testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(eventwrapper.getPickleEvent());
        }

        @DataProvider
        public Object[][] features() {
            return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
        }

        @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
        public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
            testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
        }

    }
```

Tried to achieve this using the below code. But it giving me compilation error for CustomClass loader.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = CustomClass.class.getClassLoader();
            ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new MultiLoader(classLoader);
            ClassFinder classFinder = new ResourceLoaderClassFinder(resourceLoader, classLoader);

            /* Adding cucumber plugins */
            List<String> pluginList = new ArrayList<String>();
            pluginList.add("--plugin");
            pluginList.add("html:target/cucumber-html-report");
            pluginList.add("--plugin");
            pluginList.add("json:target/cucumber.json");
            pluginList.add("--plugin");
            pluginList.add("com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:");
            pluginList.add("--plugin");
            pluginList.add("rerun:target/failedScenarios.txt");
```